# Laravel jwt returns 500, on unauthorized

Tags: laravel, jwt, laravel-8, laravel-jwt

I use jwt for my api authentication. when I use wrong token it returns 500 and I get the error that rout login is not defiend!
I'm using laravel 8 and "tymon/jwt-auth": "^1.0". my default guard is api and api driver is jwt.
I tried name login route as login, bu then I get error that get method is not supported for this route but I'm using Post method!

rout : api.php:

```
Route::group(['prefix'=>'v1'],function (){
    Route::group([
        'middleware' => 'api',
        'prefix' => 'auth'
    ], function ($router) {
        Route::post('login', 'App\Http\Controllers\AuthController@login');
        Route::post('logout', 'App\Http\Controllers\AuthController@logout');
        Route::post('refresh', 'App\Http\Controllers\AuthController@refresh');
        Route::post('me', 'App\Http\Controllers\AuthController@me');
    });

});
```

AuthController:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class AuthController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Create a new AuthController instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth:api', ['except' => ['login']]);
    }

    /**
     * Get a JWT via given credentials.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
     */
    public function login()
    {
        $credentials = request(['email', 'password']);

        if (! $token = auth()->attempt($credentials)) {
            return response()->json(['error' => 'Unauthorized'], 401);
        }

        return $this->respondWithToken($token);
    }

    /**
     * Get the authenticated User.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
     */
    public function me()
    {
        return response()->json(auth()->user());
    }

    /**
     * Log the user out (Invalidate the token).
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
     */
    public function logout()
    {
        auth()->logout();

        return response()->json(['message' => 'Successfully logged out']);
    }

    /**
     * Refresh a token.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
     */
    public function refresh()
    {
        return $this->respondWithToken(auth()->refresh());
    }

    /**
     * Get the token array structure.
     *
     * @param  string $token
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
     */
    protected function respondWithToken($token)
    {
        return response()->json([
            'access_token' => $token,
            'token_type' => 'bearer',
            'expires_in' => auth()->factory()->getTTL() * 60
        ]);
    }
}
```

user model:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Tymon\JWTAuth\Contracts\JWTSubject;

class User extends Authenticatable implements JWTSubject
{
    use HasFactory, Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];

    // Rest omitted for brevity

    /**
     * Get the identifier that will be stored in the subject claim of the JWT.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getJWTIdentifier()
    {
        return $this->getKey();
    }

    /**
     * Return a key value array, containing any custom claims to be added to the JWT.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getJWTCustomClaims()
    {
        return [];
    }
}
```

error that I get:

```
Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\RouteNotFoundException: Route [login] not defined. in file C:\wamp64\www\medrep-app\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\UrlGenerator.php on line 444

 Route [login] not defined
```

Comment: You're missing `->name('login')` on your route.. `Route::post('login', ...)->name('login');`

Comment: @ClémentBaconnier I tried this but when I use Route::post('login', ...)->name('login') I'm getting this error:
Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\MethodNotAllowedHttpException: The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST. in file C:\wamp64\www\medrep-app\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\AbstractRouteCollection.php on line 117
But I'm using Post method

Comment: Because you don't have a GET route defined. You only did POST routes

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your routes, by adding a route name, and Add a GET request for route.

```
Route::group(['prefix'=>'v1'],function (){
    Route::group([
        'middleware' => 'api',
        'as' => 'api.',
        'prefix' => 'auth'
    ], function ($router) {
        Route::post('login', 'App\Http\Controllers\AuthController@login')->name('login');
        Route::get('login', 'App\Http\Controllers\AuthController@sessionExpired')->name('sessionExpired');
        Route::post('logout', 'App\Http\Controllers\AuthController@logout')->name('logout');
        Route::post('refresh', 'App\Http\Controllers\AuthController@refresh')->name('refresh');
        Route::post('me', 'App\Http\Controllers\AuthController@me')->name('me');
    });

});
```

The login & sessionExpired function may have this code as exemple:

```
public function login()
{
        dd('test token');
        $credentials = request(['email', 'password']);

        if (! $token = auth()->attempt($credentials)) {
            return response()->json(['error' => 'Unauthorized'], 401);
        }

        return $this->respondWithToken($token);
}
public function sessionExpired()
{
   return response()->json(['error' => 'session expired'],401);
}
```

In Postman make sure you are using POST method:

[image]

Comment: now I get this error: Error: Exceeded maxRedirects. Probably stuck in a redirect loop http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/auth/login

Comment: @siavash, What are you using in Frontend to consume those API?

Comment: I'm using postman to use those API

Comment: @siavash, I Update my Answer, it works just make sure with the action method is POST type